# Linear Algebra 4th ed. Friedberg, Sec 2.7 exercise 12.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the solution space of an $n^{th}$-order homogeneous linear differential equation with constant coefficients having auxiliary polynomial $p(t)$. Prove that if $p(t) = g(t)h(t)$, where $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ are polynomials of positive degree, then 
$N(MD)) = R(g(Dv)) = p(D)(V)$, 
where $Dv: V \rightarrow V$ is defined by $Dv(x) = x'$ for $x \in V$. Hint: First prove $g(D)(V) \subset N(/i(D))$. Then prove that the two spaces have the same finite dimension.

Proof from Solution available in PDF format
: 
The second equality is the deﬁnition of range. To prove the ﬁrst equality, we observe that $R(g(DV)) \subset N(h(D))$ since $h(D)(g(D)(V))=p(D)(V)=\{0\}$.

My problems :
1. I cannot understand exactly what $Dv$ means here.
Why is it $D(V)$ and it is $g(Dv)$? what is the exact concept of $Dv$ here? 
2. Even if I understand difference of $D$ and $Dv$, I don't think I can understand every step of the proof. Please explain every step with detail, or make a new easy-to-understand proof.

p.s. If my explanation of my lack of understanding is vague, I apologize. Even doing so is difficult for me at this moment.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: also see: https://math.solverer.com/library/stephen_friedberg/linear_algebra/exercise_2-7-12?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link

Answer (score 0):

The differential operators are $p(D)$, $g(D)$, $h(D)$.

The range of the differential operators restricted to the domain $V$ is $R(p(D))=p(D)V$ etc. It might be that the domain is attached to the notation as $R_V(g(D))$ or $R(g(D),V)$ or in the usual domain restriction notation $g(D)\big|_{V}=g(D\big|_{V})$. Leaving out the stroke as in $g(D_V)$ might be ambiguous. By assumption, $p(D)V=\{0\}$.

The factorization is also valid for the differential operators, $p(D)=g(D)h(D)$. Thus
$$
g(D)h(D)V=\{0\}\implies R(g(D))=g(D)V\subset N(h(D)).
$$

Please report back after fixing/correcting the notation. Give more details on the proof around the parts you do not understand, it helps to get what idea is implemented there.